# How to stop scrollview zoomable in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm new about Xamarin forms. I have created the scrollview and inside the some content. It's working fine. But I want to stop Zoom option.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="600" WidthRequest="150" />
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Any idea how to disable zoom option? It should have default option in Xamarin form.

Comment: What is the Zoom option you are talking about? There is nothing like that in Xamarin forms for a Scroll View

Comment: Xamarin.Forms does not do anything special for scrolling, it is feature of underlying platform Android/iOS/Windows that provide UI virtualization to improve speed.You can use custom renderer to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean about zoom?ScrollView is disable zoom in dafault.